# Using Merge in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Is there any possible way we can use `join` in `merge` statement?

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 T
   USING TABLE2
   ON .....
   WHEN MATCHED THEN .....
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (X,Y,Z1) VALUES (X,Y,Z1);
```

X and Y belong TABLE2 and no problem with merging, but I also want to insert Z1 from another TABLE3, when merging into TABLE1.

I am trying to join TABLE3 but it's not allowed in Merging syntax.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Try using a subquery in place of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `USING` clause can take a subquery as its argument.  It sounds like you want something like this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 t
USING (
  ... subquery joining TABLE2 and TABLE3 ...
) f
ON f.something = t.something
...
```